# Is it a good idea to identify a mysql entry directly by its id with REST?

Tags: php, mysql, api, rest, security

For example i have a field user-id in my mysql table users which identifies a user uniquely. If someone requests for example the friends list of a user i return a json array witch includes the user-id of each friend and additional data like name.

So my question is if it is an good idea to send these user-ids directly to the client. Is this insecure? Are there ways to hide the id?

Regards

Comment: Excellent answer from @tadman below.  It's also important never to trust such an ID that is sent back to the app by the client without validation... e.g. if the client says "delete message 256512" ... don't do that, without verifying that the client should indeed be allowed to request that deletion of that message.  Classic n00b error.  The client is never to be trusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if leaking the ID information from your application is a serious issue or not. If you're in a highly competitive business where knowing the number of users on your system is valuable information, or where you're worried someone might step through them sequentially to download your database systematically, scrambling them does help.

Using a cryptographically random identifier or a UUID are two of the more common ways to solve this problem. A truly random identifier offers more security but will take more care to construct as there's many ways to get this wrong.

It's worth noting that sites like Stack Overflow leak user IDs because there's no value in hiding them. For example, your profile link has the user ID in it: 2441032.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I noticed that even facebook leaks the user IDs https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=4. Anyways uuids would look more professional but cost alot of performance.

Comment: There's not really a huge performance cost. It's just a minor bit of work to use an alternate representation for public facing interfaces. Even Ruby can generate 100K UUIDs per second.